# I dont understand this step particularly in mergesort

Tags: c, recursion, mergesort

In the above code i dont understand this. it calls merge sort again but when do merge come into play as the function repeatedly calls mergesort
 but when do merge happens
The code i could not understand is recursive one that how after breaking into halves and repeated calling of mergesort and breaking inrtoa single elment merge comes into play.
REAL QUESTION WAS HOW REAL COMES INTO PLAY

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 50000

void merge (int arr[], int start, int mid, int end){
    /* two sorted arrays arr[start ... mid]
       and arr[mid+1 ... end] merge them */
    int tempvals[MAX_SIZE];
    int ptr1, ptr2, ptrnew=0, idx;

    ptr1 = start;
    ptr2 = mid+1;

    /* compare both the sorted arrays element by element
       move the element that is smaller to the new aray */
    while ( (ptr1 <= mid) && (ptr2 <= end)){
        /* compare elements at ptr1 and ptr2 */
        if (arr[ptr1] < arr[ptr2]){
            tempvals[ptrnew] = arr[ptr1];
            ptr1 ++; ptrnew++;
        } else {
            tempvals[ptrnew] = arr[ptr2];
            ptr2 ++; ptrnew++;
        }
    }
    /* at this point --> one of the pointers has reached the end */
    while (ptr1 <= mid){
        tempvals[ptrnew] = arr[ptr1];
        ptr1 ++; ptrnew++;
    } 
    while (ptr2 <= end){
        tempvals[ptrnew] = arr[ptr2];
        ptr2 ++; ptrnew++;
    }

    /* transfer back to arr */
    for (idx = start, ptrnew = 0; idx <= end; idx++, ptrnew++)
        arr[idx] = tempvals[ptrnew];
}

void merge_sort (int arr[], int start, int end){
    int mid = (start + end)/2;
    /* termination condition */
    if( start >= end) return;

    /* recurse */
    merge_sort(arr,start, mid); /* first half */
    merge_sort (arr, mid+1, end); /* second half */
    merge (arr, start, mid, end); /* do the merging */
}
void print_array (int arr[], int size){
    int i;
    for (i=0; i < size; i++)
        printf ("%d ",arr[i]);
    printf ("\n");
}
int main(){
    int arr[MAX_SIZE]; 
    int i;
    /* initialize */
    for (i=0; i < MAX_SIZE; i++)
        arr[i] = rand(); 

    /* sort and print */
    merge_sort (arr,0, MAX_SIZE - 1);
}
```

> Blockquote

In the above code i dont understand this
   it calls merge sort again but when do merge come into play as the function repeatedly calls mergesort

```
/* recurse */
    merge_sort(arr,start, mid); /* first half */
    merge_sort (arr, mid+1, end); /* second half */
    merge (arr, start, mid, end); /* do the merging */
```

Comment: Right after the ***two*** recursive calls to `merge_sort`?

Comment: i could not understand that either.

Answer (score 0):

It's under the comment **recurse**, and called out in the line-by-line comments.  You recur on **merge_sort** to sort the left part of the array, the right part.  Then you call **merge** to reunite them, now in order.

You do *not* call **merge_sort** forever: note the base case (a.k.a. termination condition) at the top of merge_sort:

```
if( start >= end) return;
```

When you get to a list of no more than one element, you simply return -- it's already in order.  Then you crawl back up that large call chain, merging single elements, then larger lists, ... until you're done.

Comment: when i get to list of no more than one element it simply returns and goes out of the function then how merge comes into play?

Comment: What do you mean by "**crawl back up that large call chain**" @Prune

Comment: Actually, it's a binary tree, rather than a chain.  It's the tree of calls you made in getting down to single-element lists.  As you return from those, you're crawling back up the tree to the root, merging lists at each stage.  Find a textbook walk-through of merge sort and work your way through the logic and values.  Alternately, put in useful print statements to trace the execution of yoru code -- see how it works.